# Picture for Conditional Version of Law of Total Probability

Tags: probability, visualization

http://jeremykun.com/2013/03/28/conditional-partitioned-probability-a-primer/ boasts a stupendous 
[picture](http://jeremykun.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/total-probability.png?w=1800) of the (Law of) Total Probability Theorem:

[image]

$Pr(A) = \sum_n P(A|E_n) \, P(E_n)$

I'd be interested to know where I could find one for the Conditional Version of the Total Probability Theorem : 
$Pr(A|B) = \sum_n P(A|E_n \cap B) \, P(E_n|B)$

---

**Remark:** By virtue of Alex R.'s capital picture, we see:

$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(\, \color{red}{A \cap [B \cap E2]} \,) \uplus P(\, \color{red}{A \cap [B \cap E3]}\,) \uplus P(\, \color{red}{A \cap [B \cap E4]} \,)}{P(B)} $
and $ {A \cap [B \cap E_i]} = \emptyset $ for $i = 1, 5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is the full circle, green and red. The red signifies the parts of $E_n$ that contribute to $A$.

$\mbox{                                      }$

[image]

Comment: $B$ is the full circle, green and red. The red signifies the parts of $E_n$ that contribute to $A$.

Comment: Many thanks. Please let me know if you mind my edit for which I just copied and pasted your comment. I had forgotten to request an answer in the answer; comments can be harder to read.